# Preserve data on text field between calls on different activities in the same app

Tags: android, android-activity, text

I have a app that i still building, tha app has 4 activities. The number 1 has 2 texts fields. I call other activity, eg 2, when call activity number 1 back, without destroying the app, i lose every info that was in those fields. How to preserve this data. If the app is closed (destroyed) i don't want this data to be preserved. This data is not to be shared with other activities.

Comment: please post your code in activity 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`shared preference`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save data .

**save text :**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL_PREF", 0).edit();
        editor.putString("text1", Value);
        editor.commit();
```

**get text :**

```
String text1 = context.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL_PREF", 0).getString("text1", null);
```

**clear preference :**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL_PREF", 0).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
```

**clear single key :**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL_PREF", 0).edit();
        editor.remove("text1");
        editor.commit();
```